# Should I use a linked list or an array for a reorderable list of items in MongoDB (Mongoose with Next.js)?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, vercel

Using MongoDB, I want to make a list of items that users can reorder, and the order is saved to the database.

As for how this list is saved, I'd like advice on what more experienced devs would use.

Using a linked list seems like it would be more efficient than an array for updating the order of the list [O(1) vs O(n)?], but less efficient for retrieving the full list [O(n) vs O(1)?].
Am I correct about this?
Is there anything else I should be considering? I mainly just want to know how others would implement this.

I'm using Mongoose with Next.js (TypeScript) to query the database.

One possible setup I've considered:

```js
const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  description: String,
  image: String,
  firstItem: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Item",
  },
});
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  description: String,
  image: String,
  nextItem: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Item",
  },
  previousItem: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Item",
  },
});
```

Comment: How big are these lists going to be in the average and worst cases?

Comment: @user20042973 The user will decide the length and I haven't decided on implementing a max length, but I'd assume 15 average case, I'm guessing a length of 100 would be top 2%.

Comment: Sounds like its small enough that the approach probably doesn't make much of a difference. But also after rereading I think I'm a bit confused. In the proposed schema you're going to have individual documents for the list items? Have you considered embedding instead?

Comment: @user20042973 I'm not super familiar with MongoDB/Mongoose so I'm not certain how I'd go about that or what the advantages would be. Are you suggesting the the list schema contain a property that's an array of list items, but not as documents? How do you make an array of non-primitive types that don't have their own schema? 
I'd really appreciate if you could show a simple example.